# Limit of Laplacian of the distance at the origin

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, curvilinear-coordinates

Let $p$ be a point in a Riemannian manifold $M$ and $d_p$ be the distance from the point $p$. Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}\Delta d_p(x)=\infty$

I can easily prove it in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But for a general Riamannian manifold I am not sure what to do. This is what I think so far.

I know that in a coordinate system, the laplacian is written as
$$\Delta f=
  \sum_{ij}g^{ij}\big(\partial_i\partial_jf
  -\sum_k\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_kf \big)$$
This can be simplified a little if we use polar coordinates, because the basic vector fields are normal. It becomes
$$\Delta f=
  \sum_ig^{ii}\big(\partial_i^2f
  -\sum_k\Gamma_{ii}^k\partial_kf \big)$$
So for the distance, which is $x_1$ for polar, we have $\partial_ix_1=\delta_{i1}$ and thus $\partial_i^2x_1=0$ for all $i$. Therefore we have
$$\Delta x_1=
  -\sum_ig^{ii}\Gamma_{ii}^1$$
This is as far as I can go. I don't see how this would tend to infinity (or anything else)

Please let me know if I miss something. Any help or hints are welcome. Thank you

Comment: Hmm. Try doing this computation on $\mathbb R^2$ with $p=0$ and polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, so that $\Delta = \partial_r^2+\frac1r\partial_r +\frac1{r^2}\partial_\theta^2.$

Comment: I have done it, I think it works. The problem is still I have to transfer the computation to a space with curvature. Even for a 2 dimensional one, this complicates the computations

Comment: You are right, I thought it was more immediate. My idea is that it is the term $\frac1r\partial_r$ ($\frac{n-1}{r}\partial r$ in arbitrary dimension $n$) the one responsible for the blow-up at $r\to 0$; thus, I think there should be an analogous term for every Riemannian manifold. This term is buried in the Christoffel symbol but I do not see a way of exposing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use normal coordinate, the computation along this line will be easier: here we have $d=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$, $\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)=0$ so $\Gamma_{ij}^k=O(d)$; and $\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_k}(p)=0$, so $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+O(d^2)$. Take inverse we get also $g^{ij}=\delta_{ij}+O(d^2)$. Now from 
$\Delta d=g^{ij}(d_{ij}-\Gamma_{ij}^kd_k)$, by direct calculation we note $d_k=O(1)$, so $\Gamma_{ij}^kd_k\to 0$. Also by direct computation we see $d_{ij}=O(d^{-1})$; so  $g^{ij}d_{ij}=\delta_{ij}d_{ij}+O(d^2)O(d^{-1})$, with $ O(d^2)O(d^{-1})\to 0$. Thus at  distance $d$, $\Delta d$ differs from the Euclidean version by $O(d)\to 0$, the result follows from the Euclidean case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think towards the end you mean $g^{ij}d_{ij}$ instead of $f_{ij}$, right?

Comment: Yes, $f$ should be $d$.